# Unable to run bot deployed from BotBuilder Samples

Tags: azure, botframework

[image]I have tried multiple times to follow the instructions provided in 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot

to deploy the sample bot on azure. I have followed all instructions as it is as mentioned in the read me file, but I am running into some problems on local and on deployed bot as well.

**Deployed Bot:**
On sending a message, it says couldn't send retry. On checking the log it gives the following error - 
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError

**Emulator on local:**
Refresh access token failed with status code: 401

Is there some other step as well which is not mentioned in the read me file.

Comment: you sure you configured the proper secret? did you try debugging?

Comment: Can you please tell me which secret are you talking about. I am also sure its something because of secret. There are 2 passwords - One is microsoft app id and password, another is bot secret .

Comment: yeah, appId\password, thats what I'm referring to

Comment: Sorry but can you please tell me what precaution shall i take to set it. It was not there in the application settings of the web app, so i have added it manually. I have added the picture of application settings

Comment: yeah, are you sure those are the "real" ones? i think they must match with what you have in your bot dashboard

Comment: By bot dashboard, do you mean the bot application settings. I have checked the app id is same in microsoft app registration portal, application settings of web app and settings blade of bot. Is there any other link which i am missing

Comment: no, i dont think you are missing anything. i guess debugger is the next step

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187419/discussion-between-developer-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you deploy the bot you check the option in visual studio to remove additional files at destination. By default, the azure resource has a sample bot and there is probably a naming conflict.

[image]